# Spell checking message strings in .Net projects

Tags: .net, fxcop

I wanted to do a spell check for all the message strings used in my project. How can i do this using fxCop v 1.3.6??
 Or do you recommend any other microsoft tool(not third party tool) as our company does not accept that

Pls help...
Sample code i am testing with FxCop v1.3.6

```
// comment with invvvvls spellsig
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This is incorret spelling");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your strings into a resource file.  I'm using FxCop version 10, and I notice that strings in my resource files are spell-checked.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Visual Studio add-in (from VSCodeGallery). It's not from Microsoft but an integrated tool to VS:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7c8341f1-ebac-40c8-92c2-476db8d523ce

On the other hand, FxCop >= 1.36 definitely ships with internal spell checker as stated here: http://davesbox.com/archive/2008/06/08/fxcop-now-ships-with-the-spell-checker-libraries.aspx. As far as it states, you should be able to enable it with: Project -> Options -> Spelling & Analysis and settings the Spelling language drop-down, but I couldn't find the dropdown in FxCop v4.5 RC, as I don't have the v1.36 release installed.

Comment: No i am not able to do a spell check in FxCop 1.3.6

Comment: I have a simple code to test but it is not catching the spelling errors

Comment: Try the "Spell Checker" add-in that I posted just to see if that works. Maybe there is some other problem which affects spell checkers altogether.